# how can I populate the select box value with keys of an object?

Tags: angular

I have an object like here,

```
{
  "USD": {
    "symbol": "$",
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "symbol_native": "$",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "rounding": 0,
    "code": "USD",
    "name_plural": "US dollars"
  },
  "CAD": {
    "symbol": "CA$",
    "name": "Canadian Dollar",
    "symbol_native": "$",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "rounding": 0,
    "code": "CAD",
    "name_plural": "Canadian dollars"
  },
}
```

I would like to populate the select box with the keys(USD, CAD).

my current implementation,

```
public currencyList;
getCurrency() {
        let currencyCode = this.currencyDetails.getCurrencyDetails();
        for (var key in currencyCode) {
            if (currencyCode.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.currencyList.push(key);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: angularjs or angular2?

Comment: I 'am using angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through properties and add it to an array variable like below using Object.keys.

```
var obj = {
"USD": {
"symbol": "$",
"name": "US Dollar",
"symbol_native": "$",
"decimal_digits": 2,
"rounding": 0,
"code": "USD",
"name_plural": "US dollars"
},
"CAD": {
"symbol": "CA$",
"name": "Canadian Dollar",
"symbol_native": "$",
"decimal_digits": 2,
"rounding": 0,
"code": "CAD",
"name_plural": "Canadian dollars"
},
}

public currencyList;
getCurrency() {
    let currencyCode = this.currencyDetails.getCurrencyDetails();
    currencyList = Object.keys(currencyCode);
}
```

Now bind **keys** to your select box element and it would work

Comment: Thats what i actually do now. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: @kartikajas please check the updated answer. You need to use Object.keys(object) to get all keys at once

Comment: i don't understand. can you explain me that in brief?

Comment: I have updated answer relevant to your question. Object.keys() returns the keys of any object. So you can use it to fetch all your keys

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Jaykrishnan's answer is good, you can also shorten it by doing:

```
getCurrency() {
   this.currencyList = Object.keys(this.currencyDetails.getCurrencyDetails());
}
```

Then you can use the `currencyList` just fine in your template :)

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let key of currencyList">  
     {{key}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON is not valid, it should not have **`,`** at the end. You can simply use **`Object.keys(this.currencyList);`**

```
export class AppComponent {
 currencyKeys;
 currencyList = {
"USD": {
"symbol": "$",
"name": "US Dollar",
"symbol_native": "$",
"decimal_digits": 2,
"rounding": 0,
"code": "USD",
"name_plural": "US dollars"
},
"CAD": {
"symbol": "CA$",
"name": "Canadian Dollar",
"symbol_native": "$",
"decimal_digits": 2,
"rounding": 0,
"code": "CAD",
"name_plural": "Canadian dollars"
}
};
currencyKeys = Object.keys(this.currencyList);

)
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/jwXs374LmYYsq4GxCGka)**